# Is Benedict XVI the first pope emeritus?

Tags: christianity, pope, titles

I have read in a newspaper that Benedict XVI is the first pope emeritus.

Is he really the first pope in history to resign? Or does the title *pope emeritus* have more specific meaning than just a "pope who has resigned"?

Comment: I had some doubts whether to ask here or on [christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/), But I had to choose one of the two sites, so I've decided to try here.

Comment: Please read [ask] with an emphasis on the third bullet under what not to ask.  It might also help to read [this](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/642/1401). Questions that dispute an assertion with no research should be out of scope for H:SE.  If you have a reasons to doubt the assertion, please provide it. If you want to discuss the term, please use a discussion forum.

Comment: Hmmm. I *thought* we'd had this question, but no. It seems like it ought to have been asked already though, so I'm glad we have it now. :-)

Comment: @Martin It would have been a duplicate: [What Popes have resigned in the past?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14107)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, he is absolutely not the first to resign. There has been several resignations in Papal history, not all of which are undisputed or voluntary, though admittedly none in recent centuries. Some examples include:

- [Benedict IX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Benedict_IX), resigned in 1045.
- [Gregory VI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Gregory_VI), resigned in 1046.
- [Celestine V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Celestine_V), resigned in 1294.

Celestine V in particular laid down the [canon law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_law_(Catholic_Church)) basis for popes to abdicate. The current provisions are provided in contained in [Canon 332](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P16.HTM) of the [1983 Code of Canon Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Code_of_Canon_Law).

All previous popes who had resigned or abdicated their positions may be justifiably referred to as "pope emeritus", which basically just means "retired pope". In this sense, Benedict XVI is definitely not the first, either.

However, Benedict XVI *does* seem to be the first to be **officially** styled "Pope Emeritus".

Comment: I know when last I looked at it, most such situations came about due to political disputes. What's probably new now is that the advent of modern medicine allows for a situation where the Catholic Church is liable to end up with popes who are unable to fully perform their duties for decades at a time if there isn't some provision for them retiring before death.

Comment: Oh, I thought Celestine V was the only one, instead!